# Expected Value of Big Theta(n)

Tags: algorithms

I'm reading through an algorithms book in preparation for an upcoming course. I came across the following statements:

\begin{equation}
E[\theta(n)] = \theta(n)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}E[O(n_i^2)] = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}O[E(n_i^2)]
\end{equation}

How do these equalities follow? I guess I might be a little confused with some of the terminology. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For the second equation, it looks like the O is being treated as a constant, but I'm not sure why it is being treated so...

To clarify: these equations relate to Bucket Sort and the 
\begin{equation}
n_i
\end{equation}
is a random variable denoting the number of elements placed in a particular bucket.

[here's the original equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Byt1.jpg)

[Further clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsfVR.jpg)

C.22: E[aX] = aE[x], where a is a constant

Comment: Really difficult to tell without context. What is $\theta$? A deterministic function $\theta: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$? A sequence of RVs? If the latter why is the expectation trivial, when $\mathbb{E}(c)=c$ only for constants $c$, unless the author is really doing conditional expectation like $\mathbb{E}(\theta_n | \mathscr{F}_n)=\theta_n$ where $\theta_n$ is $\mathscr{F}_n$-measurable. Without more context from the source, it’s really difficult to parse what is intended by the notation...

Comment: The context is algorithm analysis. Theta, as in Big Theta, is standard algorithm notation. I probably shouldn't have tagged it with "probability" lol

Comment: If there is "no probability," then what does "E" represent?

Comment: As made clear by the title, "E" is expected value.

Comment: "It looks like the O is being treated as a constant" isn't the O the "big-O" notation $O(\cdot)$? It's not a number or a "constant."

Comment: Now I realize, this is about $O(n^2)$ big-O notation and $\Theta(n)$ the Big theta notation. Since expectations are here probably the probabilistic analogs are relevant. You could edit the question to clarify. I don’t know how rigorous this book is so you should try to find where the author defines these concepts, cuz as far as I’ve learned, $O(g)$ is neither a constant, a function, nor an operator. It is a set of functions satisfying the relevant bounds near the asymptote. But many informal manipulations treating it as a function are inevitably valid, so various texts take this approach.

Comment: @Mark Then there must be an underlying probability distribution. Are the $n$ and $n_i$ random variables?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation and here is the wikipedia for some of the probabilistic analogs, for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated the question to clarify a bit

Comment: @NapD.Lover I've seen the author manipulate equations like this: () = cn.


So, given that, I can do something like this: E[()] = E[cn] = cE[n] = O(E[n])

This seems like an abuse of notation to me, though...

Comment: Okay so apparently equation C.22, whatever that is, justifies the interchange of big-$O$ and $\mathbb{E}$, whatever that means. I could guess one meaning might be if $X_n \in O_p(n)$ in stochastic boundedness, then $E(X_n) \in O(n)$ in the standard sense of Big O as $n\to \infty$. But check the book for their own definitions.

Comment: I updated the post with C.22

Comment: @Mark okay yes this ties back to the end of my second comment. It is technically an abuse of notation, but is very popular and often intuitive. The wikipedia page for the standard big O talks about the notation, invalid manipulations, etc if you want more info.